# The number of symmetric arrangements of pairs

Tags: combinatorics

let's say you have $n$ indistinguishable pairs you want to arrange among each other. What is the number of arrangements that are symmetrical? For clarification,
the number of arrangements of $n$ pairs is $\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$, so for two
pairs there are 3 arrangements, which are:

$1122,\, $ Which is the same as $2211$

$1221,\,$ which is the same as $2112$

$1212,\,$ which is the same as $2121$

My question is how to count the arrangements that are symmetrical
(if you reverse the arrangement you get the same arrangement). All of the
above arrangements are symmetrical. An example of an asymmetrical one for
$n=3$ is

$121233$

Edit: two of the same digits represents a pair. However, the pairs are 
indistinguishable.

Comment: It's not clear what you're getting at.  Do you mean that each digit is used the same number of times?  How is $1122$ "symmetrical"?

Comment: The digits represent pairs. I used different numbered digits so it's less confusing, but the different numbered pairs are indistinguishable. Youre arranging the pairs in a string. What is unclear, specifically?

Comment: I don't see how $1122$ is an arrangement such that "if you reverse the arrangement you get the same arrangement".

Comment: Because the pairs are indistinguishable. The numbering is just so you can tell where the pairs are placed. If it helps, you can represent the specific sequence $1122$ as $()()$, each pair is a set of parentheses. If you flip $()()$ down the middle it stays the same. I did say that $$1122$$ is the same as $$2211$$.

Comment: never mind! We're good. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: $121233$ is like $(())()$ if you reverse it you get $331212$ which is $()(())$ which is not the same. Edit: nevermind. but will leave this here for future people to clarify because i guess it was confusing.